# How to upload a file in share point server from a local machine connected through lan using c#

Tags: c#, sharepoint, spsite

I am really new to this share point stuffs.We have a share point server with admin account in it and i was connecting it from my local machine through ip and share point port manually.
Nut i need to write a program which needs to upload the files into the share point server from the local machine to server. Is it possible in using winforms ? or only possible in web services.?

```
   using (SPSite oSite = new SPSite(sharePointSite))
{
    using (SPWeb oWeb = oSite.OpenWeb())
    {
        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(fileToUpload))
            throw new FileNotFoundException("File not found.", fileToUpload);    



    SPFolder myLibrary = oWeb.Folders[documentLibraryName];

    // Prepare to upload
    Boolean replaceExistingFiles = true;
    String fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileToUpload);
    FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(fileToUpload);

    // Upload document
    SPFile spfile = myLibrary.Files.Add(fileName, fileStream, replaceExistingFiles);

    // Commit 
    myLibrary.Update();
}
```

}

tried using the above code and i getting error from the following line

> using (SPSite oSite = new SPSite(sharePointSite))

and the error was

> "The Web application at http://server:port/ could not be found. Verify that you have typed the URL correctly. If the URL should be serving existing content, the system administrator may need to add a new request URL mapping to the intended application"

and am not able to upload the file.
But if i copied and paste the same URL in my local machine i can able to access the sharepoint deployed in server and i can even upload files manually from my local machine.

How to upload a file in sharepoint server from the local machine connected with LAN..??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**siteURL** = Main URl of the sharepoint (eg)  "http://10.0.0.14:48487/";

**documentListName** = any of the folders in shrepoint (eg) Shared Documents

**documentName** = name of the file (eg)sampleword.docx , readme.txt etc

**documentStream** =  the byte format of the file which we going to upload.

> (**eg**)byte[] bytefile = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filepath+filename);

```
public static void UploadDocument(string siteURL, string documentListName, string documentListURL,string documentName, byte[] documentStream = null)
    {  

     try
        {
        using (SP.ClientContext clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteURL))
        {

            #region"Only if you have credentials"
            NetworkCredential Cred = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
            clientContext.Credentials = Cred;
            #endregion


            SP.List documentsList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(documentListName);

            var fileCreationInformation = new SP.FileCreationInformation();
            //Assign to content byte[] i.e. documentStream

            fileCreationInformation.Content = documentStream;
            //Allow owerwrite of document

            fileCreationInformation.Overwrite = true;
            //Upload URL

            fileCreationInformation.Url = documentName;

            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadFile = documentsList.RootFolder.Files.Add(
                fileCreationInformation);


            uploadFile.ListItemAllFields.Update();
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

}

This works perfect for me :) :)

Answer (score 0):

make sure your connecting to an existing site collection.   the error you have received is quite self explainitory,  it cannot find the site collection you have pointed it at.   check your string `sharePointSite` to make sure there isn't a typo and that it's accessing the correct root site collection.   Remember with SharePoint SPSite = Site Collection   SPWeb = a website in a site collection.

i can't see any glaring errors in your code without running something up myself except to make sure that when you are calling oSite.openweb() it's for a single site within the site collection.

Comment: But if i copy and paste the same URL in my local machine i can able to access the sharepoint deployed in server and i can even upload files manually from my local machine.The only thing is i need to give the credentials

Comment: oh,  check your build options,  make sure platform target: is set to `any CPU`

Comment: yes it was set to anyCpu only.. and its ASP.Net web project.